# Wrapping head around sequential GitHub Actions

Tags: python, github-actions, python-poetry

I am wanting to run some sequential GitHub Actions. I have a GitHub action for a data cleaning step and then another one to produce some topline reports from these data.

My thoughts were, that I could do a process like so.

```
setup.yml --> clean.yml --> topline.yml
```

This is what setup.yml looks like:

```
name: setup

on: 
  workflow_call:

    
jobs:
  installation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        id: checkout-repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install python
        id: setup-python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.11
      - name: Load cached poetry intallation
        id: cached-poetry
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.local
          key: poetry-0
      - name: Install poetry
        uses: snok/install-poetry@v1
        with:
          virtualenvs-create: true
          virtualenvs-in-project: true
          installer-parallel: true
      - name: Load cached virtual environment
        id: cached-poetry-dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: .venv
          key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.setup-python.outputs.python-version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.cached-poetry-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: poetry install --no-interaction --no-root
      - name: Install project
        run: poetry install --no-interaction
      - name: Install Quarto
        id: install-quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2
      - name: Activate poetry shell
        id: activate-poetry
        run: source .venv/bin/activate
```

Then, my hope was that I could then execute a python file that cleans the data

```
name: cleaning

on: 
    workflow_call:

jobs:
    execute-cleaning:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Execute cleaning script
            run: |
              python src/twenty-three/sp-2023.py
```

Then, once the cleaning step is complete, I was hoping that I could then produce the topline reports with a topline workflow.

```
name: topline

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  execute-topline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Render the topline file
        id: render-topline
        run: |
          quarto render src/twenty-three/sp-2023-topline.qmd
```

All of these steps are managed with a file called build.yml

```
name: build

on: [push]

jobs:
  call-setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/setup.yml
  call-clean:
    needs: call-setup
    uses: ./.github/workflows/clean.yml
  call-topline:
    needs: call-clean
    uses: ./.github/workflows/topline.yml
```

The problem that I am running into is that between each of these workflows, things seem to restart.

I've looked around at some of the documentation and I am new to GitHub Actions. So I am getting a little bit confused. Is my problem that I am using `workflow_call` instead of `workflow_run`? Would using `workflow_run` in my `build.yml` allow me to hand-off things from one workflow to the next, or do I have to store data from one to the next? I am just a little bit confused as to what the most efficient way to do this would be. I would definitely not prefer to have to re-install Python and my dependencies for the `clean` and `topline` workflows, that seems like a bit of a waste. Thus, trying to do things sequentially like this.

I am sorry if this might seem like a duplicate question and I have looked around quite a bit, but I could really use someone helping me out by explaining some of the logic and where my confusion is coming from here.

Comment: What do you mean "things seem to restart"? If those steps all need the same dependencies, why put them in different _jobs_ let alone _workflows_?

Comment: Each job runs in a new runner instance (`ubuntu-latest` in your case). I would suggest gather all workflows in the same file (and in the same job) to start with, and then focus on workflow management / optimization once you'll gain more experience with the tool.

Comment: Thanks @GuiFalourd. I guess I was interested in separating things out mostly to try to learn how these things work. So, would you say that it just isn't ever really worth it to separate these out into different jobs? One concern I had was trying to find a way to avoid the jobs getting super long and unwieldy as I add some more components. I thought breaking things up would make it a bit easier to manage. But it seems that your recommendation would suggest that it just something I'd need to live with as doing it in one job is the right way to go?

Comment: I also want to add a workflow for unit tests, so I thought it might be good to basically have a job that "sets up" my dependencies and then let it fork between sequential workflows for building the tool when there is a PR and then one for testing when pushing a commit to a development branch.

Comment: At first going with 1 job is easier and will make it easier to identify eventual problemas. Here, you're already trying to optimize the workflow management. It's not a bad idea, but as you're new to GitHub Actions and still experiencing how it work, I would wait a little before going deeper.

Comment: Regarding the setup, you could eventually use [cache](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) or eventually [self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) in the future to speed-up workflows.